# superset ui chart type is not register

Tags: reactjs, apache-superset

I'm trying to integration superset-ui to Reactjs Application. I follow the [document on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superset-ui/legacy-plugin-chart-pivot-table) and as well as [sample on github](https://github.com/apache-superset/superset-ui/blob/master/packages/superset-ui-demo/storybook/stories/plugins/legacy-plugin-chart-pivot-table/Stories.tsx), but when I start the project it shows the error

> ERROR chartType="pivot-table" —Error: Item with key "pivot-table" is not registered.

Here is my code

```
import { SuperChart } from '@superset-ui/core';
import PivotTableChartPlugin from '@superset-ui/legacy-plugin-chart-pivot-table';

new PivotTableChartPlugin().configure({ key: 'pivot-table' }).register();

const PivotTable = () => {

  const datasource = {
    columnFormats: {},
    verboseMap: {
      sum__num: 'sum__num',
    },
  };

  return (
    <SuperChart
      chartType="pivot-table"
      width={400}
      height={400}
      datasource={datasource}
      queriesData={[{ /* sample data */ }]}
    />
  );
}
export default PivotTable;
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem and launch your application?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
new PivotTableChartPlugin().configure({ key: 'pivot_table' }).register();
```

it's not pivot-table it's pivot_table

Comment: No, It doesn't work. As on demo, they are using storybook, so I am not sure if it is required.

Comment: `key` can be any string. [Documentation](https://github.com/apache-superset/superset-ui/tree/master/plugins/legacy-plugin-chart-pivot-table).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by taking code from their open source React Dashboard. Note this works for superset version 1.5.0 and may not work for their newer 2.1.0 version

```
import { Preset } from '@superset-ui/core';
import PivotTableChartPlugin from '@superset-ui/legacy-plugin-chart-pivot-table';

class MainPreset extends Preset {
  constructor() {
    super({
      name: 'Legacy Charts',
      plugins: [
        new PivotTableChartPlugin().configure({ key: 'pivot_table' }),
      ],
    });
  }
}

// call setupPlugins() on app load before you try to render the chart
export default function setupPlugins() {
  new MainPreset().register();
}
```

This seems like a more complicated way of doing the same thing you are already doing but it's worth giving it a try.

If this still does not work for you my guess is that the register function is an async process that takes time to execute and if you try to render the chart before it is finished it will give you this error. I have yet to find any promise or callback associated with the register function.

Try playing with executing the register function some time before you try rendering the chart and seeing if that works as well.